# GAE : Yahoo, Google & Facebook login support

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, facebook-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints, yahoo-oauth

Over Google Application Engine, I want to add Yahoo, Google & Facebook login options for the users in my application.

Since Facebook does not support federated login using openid, how could I implement login option for all facebook, yahoo & google using JavaScript in my application?

Is OAuth only way to implement all three facebook, yahoo & google login options?
If Yes, is there any sample code to refer to implement using 
a. java script + google cloud endpoints?
b. java servlets?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of toolkits out there that should help you; for example, have a look at oauth.io.  If you have to roll it yourself, talking to FB/G/Y at the raw HTTP/JSON level is not actually that hard.  In the case of Google there’s the Google+ Sign-In widget that is pretty slick, and FB of course has similar stuff.

It’s not java servlet, but in https://code.google.com/p/favcolor-accountchooser/source/browse/rp.rb there’s Ruby source code for doing OAuth authentication to Google, FB, and Microsoft Live (but not Yahoo)